# Copy files from Amazon s3 to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3

I found similar questions, but none of them answers my question: Where should I store the credentials when moving files between Hadoop and S3 using hadoop distcp or s3-dist-cp?

I created a new Amazon EMR cluster and now I want to copy files from a S3 bucket. The following approaches do not work:

1. Using `hadoop distcp`
   I encoded the credentials within the url like that: `hadoop distcp s3n://<awsaccesskey>:<awssecrectkey>@<backetname>/path hdfs://<path>` but it seems like the software is not able to handle aws secret keys containing a `+` or a `/`, which is quite often the case. Encoding the keys using url encode does not work, but yields to another error like:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bucket name must not be formatted as an IP Address

or

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bucket name should not contain uppercase characters

2. Using s3-dist-cp
   So I used the "better" approach, but with the same result.

How can I encode the credentials or where to store them if they contain special chars? I also tried ENV variables (e.g. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY) without success. Some tutorials mention a `core-site.xml` file, but no location. So I searched for it and there are multiple matches. The tutorials say that it's mandatory to copy this files to all nodes, but why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try URL encoding the key with special characters?

Comment: Yes, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<awsaccesskey>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<awssecrectkey>
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3a.access.key="${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" -Dfs.s3a.secret.key="${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}" s3a://<bucketname>/<path> <hdfs_path>
```